# List of times between two TimeSpans

Tags: c#, timespan

I'm trying to create a list of time spans between 2 time spans. For Example

23:55 -> 00:10

should give me

```
23:55
00:00
00:05
00:10
```

This is my code but I get an out of memory exception

```
var times = new List<TimeSpan>();
int interval = 5;
TimeSpan start = TimeSpan.Parse("23:55");
TimeSpan end = TimeSpan.Parse("00:00");
DateTime datum = new DateTime();
for (var dt = start; dt <= end; dt = datum.AddMinutes(interval) - datum)
{
   times.Add(dt);
}
```

Comment: Have you tried debugging it? That should help solving the problem.

Comment: if you have a loop and you get out of memory then most likely the reason is that loop is _infinite_.

Comment: @MichaelPetrotta `datum.AddMinutes(interval) - datum` produces a timepsan

Comment: I misread what was being added to the List, mea culpa. But: correct your `interval` declaration.

Comment: @MichaelPetrotta well spotted. Code updated

Comment: `TimeSpan` is primarily designed for *elapsed time*, not *time of day*.  It won't loop over at midnight on its own.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should compare dates to timespans.In your code for example `dt <= end` will be false from the start because 23:55 is greater than 00:10.Instead try it like this using datetime(creating bogus dates like i do or if you are behind this example using datetimes better,once you see it you will understand):

```
var times = new List<TimeSpan>();
double interval = 5;
//TimeSpan start = TimeSpan.Parse("23:55");
//TimeSpan end = TimeSpan.Parse("00:10");
DateTime starting = new DateTime(2014, 1, 1, 23, 55, 0);
DateTime ending = new DateTime(2014, 1, 2, 0, 10, 0);
for (var ts = starting; ts <= ending; ts = ts.AddMinutes(interval))
{
    times.Add(ts.TimeOfDay);
}
```

Output:

```
23:55
00:00
00:05
00:10
```

Comment: This saved me a lot of time, trying to figure it out on my own. Thanks for sharing.

Answer (score 2):

Your datum value never changes here, so you're looping over the same time over and over. You're not going from start to end, you're going from datum (which starts as now) and then each iteration setting dt to datum.addMinutes(interval) - datum.

Comment: doesn't the addMinutes(interval) change the datum?

Comment: It may, I'm not sure. That said, it still never goes from start to end, and may be outside of that range to begin with, unless end is in the future.

Comment: Not only does datum never change (since it's never altered anywhere) but dt never really changes either (despite being altered).  Hence the infinite loop.  Each time dt gets 5 minutes added to datum, but then you subtract the old datum.  That's equivalent of making dt a 5-minute time span each iteration.

Answer (score 1):

I suspect your loop is infinite because of this:

```
dt = datum.AddMinutes(interval) - datum
```

`datum` has never changed as well as the `interval` so `dt` has always the same value.

A cleaner approach which uses Linq instead of loops could be used as follows::

```
TimeSpan diff = end - start;
var times = Enumerable
           .Range(0, (int)(diff.Minutes / interval) + 1)
           .Select(x => start.Add(TimeSpan.FromMinutes(interval * x)))
           .ToList();
```

Comment: Thanks. I find Linq very hard to wrap my head around. Also the end time doesn't make it into the list

Comment: @totalitarian add +1 after `(int)(diff.TotalMinutes / interval)`

Comment: Thanks but it doesn't seem to work. `Specified argument was out of the range of valid values.
Parameter name: count`

Comment: @totalitarian sorry my mistake, change TotalMinutes to Minutes